# Using VSCode WSL Remote, why won't Chrome Debugger launch Chrome for Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-debugger, vscode-remote

I'm switching to VSCode WSL Remote mode for a JavaScript project. The Chrome Debugger Extension always look for Google Chrome in Linux. Is this the correct behavior?

I have a Chrome for Linux installed in WSL, which could run on X server. The problem is that the breakpoints are not working.

I've tried removing Chrome in WSL, the extension will then throw `Can't find Chrome - install it or set the "runtimeExecutable" field in the launch config`.

Should I set "runtimeExecutable" to `chrome.exe` or force it to run on local side with

```
"remote.extensionKind": {
    "msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome": "ui",
}
```

Could I correct some config so that the Chrome Debugger can find the Chrome in Windows if there's no Linux install?

Is there any official guide for it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should set

```
"remote.extensionKind": {
"msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome": "ui"}
```

An alternative would be to set an alias `chrome` to go to chrome.exe in Windows. To ensure persistence, add it to your `~.bashrc` or shell equivalent or alternatively `.profile`.

Side note: you should be able to debug with the new chromium-based Edge as well if you prefer using that.

Comment: Hi, can you share on how to create an alias `chrome` to call some exe windows?

Comment: ```alias chrome="\"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe\"" ```Change the path as needed.  You can do similar for any other windows executable.